# What are the surfaces that contain an interior volume (space separating) called? Are they related to orientability?

Tags: general-topology, volume, surfaces, klein-bottle, non-orientable-surfaces

I know that a "closed" surface is defined as a compact surface with no boundary. I don't have it clear if they have something to do with having an interior volume (completely enclosed volume). The Klein bottle seems to be a closed surface but it does not have an enclosed volume.

Is there a necessary and sufficient property or classification of surfaces that characterizes the ones that do enclose a volume?

By the way, I'm looking into this because I want to characterize the correct kind of surfaces where Gauss's Law (for electric fields) applies in Physics.

Comment: You might be looking for the Jordan-Brouwer decomposition theorem, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem#Proof_and_generalizations

Comment: Sufficient would also be that the surface is orientable with continuous unit normal, compact without boundary, pathwise connected and at least $C^1$. This can be shown with Gauss's divergence theorem and some topological considerations. This would be ranked as a rather difficult exercise for advanced students in integration theory.

Comment: Thanks @humanStampedist! I knew it was kind of similar to the Jordan Curve theorem. I missed the description in Wikipedia. Your second comment about having all those properties just for sufficiency, is that exercise in some book? By integration theory, do you  mean differential topology? 
Also, I wonder why so many Physics Theorems such as (the Physics) Gauss's theorem which uses concepts such as enclosed volume do not have a Math version that states it rigorously (for dealing with enclosed charge).